# is there a way of running celery worker in debug mode; much like flask debug?

Tags: python, celery

- I find myself having to manually restart celery worker whenever I make a change to the task source code
- Is there a faster way of coding/debugging celery tasks?
- Something similar to how flask can be run in DEBUG=1 mode; where changes in the HTML and routes are automatically reloaded
- I am currently running celery worker in a docker container with the following command:

`celery worker -l info -A celery_tasks.app -n celery_worker -B`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing built in but you can use the `watchmedo` utility from [watchdog](https://github.com/gorakhargosh/watchdog) which monitors a directory for file changes and allows you to restart your worker.

You just need to install it with `pip`:

```
pip install watchdog[watchmedo]
```

And run:

```
watchmedo auto-restart --directory=./ --pattern="*.py" --recursive -- celery worker -l info -A celery_tasks.app -n celery_worker -B
```

Comment: Would --directory be my task root directory? I have my tasks separated into multiple sub-directories ; I imagine that is what the --recursive flag implies?

Comment: It would be the root of your project I would say, you need to monitor every python file involved in your tasks, not only the tasks themselves. The recursive flag allows to monitor not only the root directory but also every nested one.

Comment: I have the process running.../usr/bin/python3.6 /usr/local/bin/watchmedo auto-restart --directory=/celery_tasks --pattern=*.py --recursive ....

Comment: I made a change to a logging statement for one of my files...but it does not seem like it made any change. Is there a log file I can use to troubleshoot? The directory I am using is the root of my application

Comment: Are you synching your project directory between the host and the docker container? Make sure your files are changing inside the container, as a test you could manually go inside the container and make a change from there.

Comment: Interesting case.  When I make the change to the file on the docker container itself; celery restarts automatically as you mentioned. However when I make the change on my pycharm editor...(Even though I have the volume configured between my host and the container) the restart does NOT occur. When I exec into the container and ls -lrt. I can see that the file has updated and the timestamp of the change aswell. But no celery worker restart :(

Comment: Are you on windows? If yes, because of a limitation of CIFS, the container is not notified about file changes, to solve this problem you can use [this tool](https://github.com/merofeev/docker-windows-volume-watcher/), you would need to keep it running while developing

Comment: Brilliant! Worked like a charm. Yes I am on windows, so installing the tool got things working :)